# Representative point of a cluster with L1 distance

Tags: clustering, matlab, k-means, distance-functions

The representative point of a cluster or cluster center for the k-means algorithm is the component-wise mean of the points in its cluster. The mean is chosen because it helps to minimize the **within cluster variances** (which is to say that it is minimizing within cluster squared Euclidean distance, since its the same). Now, when I want to use a different distance metric, like L1 (Manhattan distance), I would be minimizing the **within cluster absolute deviations** (if I choose to). I was looking at what the centers calculation would be like, because the mean won't reduce the new objective function, and I found this on the Matlab documentation of their `kmeans` function for the distance parameter

> `cityblock` - Sum of absolute differences, i.e., the L1 distance. Each centroid is the component-wise median of the points in that cluster.

Now, how did they come up with the component-wise median? How does a median minimize absolute deviations?

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34613/l1-regression-estimates-median-whereas-l2-regression-estimates-mean for most of the answer.

Comment: @NickCox : Fantastic. Thank you for such a quick response.

Comment: @user603: I see that the geometric median is quiet different from the component-wise median. What were you implying?

Comment: The geometric median is AFAICT known as medoid in clustering, as in k-medoids and PAM. For L1, use the component wise median, as the distance is separable in individual components.

Answer (score 3):

The component-wise median can be used.

This is known as **k-medians** in clustering literature.

If you instead take the most central instance, you can use arbitrary distance functions. This is then known as **k-medoids** - where the medoid is the most central object of a cluster.